# :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMerger IllegalStateException using AS 3.0 beta6

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I've started getting following error after updating to AS 3.0 beta 6.  Has anyone else come across this?  I'm only seeing this error when I try to build/run from AS.....no issue if I run gradle on command line.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerFor<BuildVariantName>Debug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Comment: My rule of thumb is: Whenever you see "Dex" error in Gradle build, try clean and rebuild.

Comment: Had tried that but didn't help.

Comment: Then try turning off instant run, and also try enabling/disabling multidex

Comment: Thank you. Enabling Instant Run helps and fix that issue in AS. Unfortunately I can't build on the command line . Which means for us it is not a "long term" solution...

Comment: We also don't have instant run enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [@Nabin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5137352/nabin-bhandari) in the comments we found out that **enabling Instant Run** fix that issue.

Unfortunately - other than the original poster - we had the same issue on the command line. Which means our CI doesn't run.

We found out that we can **disabling** the incremental dexing by setting the flag `-Pandroid.useDexArchive=false`. [See here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/2-5-alpha-gradle-plugin/trying-gradle-plugin-2-5) for more infos:

> A new incremental dexing pipeline has been implemented. Now the Gradle plugin dex only the class files that have changed. It is enabled by default, but you can disable it by doing one of the following:
>
> Passing -Pandroid.useDexArchive=false when running builds from command line e.g. ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug -Pandroid.useDexArchive=false.
>
> Adding android.useDexArchive=false to the gradle.properties file in your root project.

Luckily we don't need incremental dexing on our CI.

Unfourtnaly it doesn't help us in **Android Studio with disabled Instant Run**!

Comment: Thanks @StefMa, setting `android.useDexArchive` to false fixed issue for me.  What are implications of settings this (couldn't find any documentation on it)?

Comment: I've linked the documentation and quoted it from there . If we set it to false the gradle plugin will dex all files for each run. Instead of just the files which have changed. Which leads obviously to longer build times.

Comment: In my case, the only thing that fixed it was "Adding android.useDexArchive=false to the gradle.properties file in your root project."